# jpa repository delete children without loading parent collection

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to delete a Child Entity using Child's Repository. I do not want to load the whole Collection of Child in Parent and remove a Child from there because the collection is huge in some cases and can cause memory issues. But after I delete a child when I load the Parent using Parent Repository I get an error that says "Deleted Entity passed to persists".

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USR")
public class User {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<UserApplication> userApplications = new HashSet<UserApplication>();

}


@Entity
@Table(name="USR_2_APL")
public class UserApplication  {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USR_SK")
    private User user;

}


@Test
public void testDeleteUserApp() {

    List<UserApplication> removedUserApp = userApplicationRepository.findByUserSkAndApplicationSk(1, 5);

    userApplicationRepository.delete(removedUserApp);

    //*****This is where I see an error that says 
    //org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: deleted entity passed to persist: [UserApplication#<null>]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException
    userRepository.findByUserLoginName(loginId); 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to flush (or refresh) after the delete?

Comment: Yes, I did try to flush right after the delete. I am getting the error on flush in that case
userApplicationRepository.flush();

Answer (score 0):

I donot know if this will help you but I have something similar and this is what I do to delete the data...

In the repository I have a method like this:-

```
@Transactional
public Long deleteByByUserSkAndApplicationSk(int userSk, int applicationSk);
```

The output of the method is the number of rows deleted.

Then you can directly call the method where ever you want to delete.